# jQuery append span if parent class exists

Tags: jquery, class, append, html

Here's my goal:

If any parent `<li>` has class `outofstock`, I want to append a `<span>` inside `.inner_product_header` (after the `onsale` span).

My code:

### HTML:

```
<ul class="products">
<li class="product outofstock"> <a href="#">
    Test text description
        <div class="inner_product_header">
            <span class="onsale">On Sale</span>
        </div>
    </a>

</li>
<li class="product"> <a href="#">
    Test text description
    <div class="inner_product_header">
            <span class="onsale">On Sale</span>
        </div>
    </a>

</li>
</ul>
```

### JS:

```
$(function() {

    if ( $( 'ul.products li.product' ).hasClass( 'outofstock' ) ) {

    $(this).children('.inner_product_header').append('<span class="itscomingsoon">Coming Soon</span>');

}

});
```

Here's my jsFiddle with styling to see the blocks: http://jsfiddle.net/8szFV/4/

I can't tell where I'm going wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you're using `$(this)`, but you're not in an event handler or `.each()` loop that binds `this`.

But you can do it all in a one-liner.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("ul.products li.product.outofstock .inner_product_header").append('<span class="itscomingsoon">Coming Soon</span>');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kzULq/1)

Comment: Thanks @Barmar! Definitely a more concise solution. On my site, though, it's still not appending the span after the `onsale` span.

Comment: Weird, because it's not working on the live site: http://lifelongu.com/life-balance/. It's loading the `.js` fine, but  no `<span>Coming Soon!</span>` is showing up inside any of the `.inner_product_header`s.

Comment: Found it, comingsoon.js. You need to wrap it in `$(function() ...)` as in your question, so it will run after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: @Barmar: This code still won't work since he is using `.noConflict()`

Comment: Fixed my answer to deal with that.

Comment: Perfect! Sorry for my naiveté. This is it though! In the case of Wordpress, the first call needs to be in noConflict (`jQuery`), then everything inside can be `$`. ...for anyone else referencing this in the future. Thanks again @Barmar & @Hybrid